# command not found: vcpkg after downloading it in macOS

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

I am trying to open an OpenCV project using Vscode in macOS. To run it, I need to download the OpenCV packages.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMl1N.png

Then I was led to the vcpkg web page and tried to install it following the instructions.

Step 1: Clone the vcpkg repo

> git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git

Step 2: Run the bootstrap script to build vcpkg

> `./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh`

After Step 2, the following texts were showed in the terminal:

```
/vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
Downloading vcpkg-macos...
Telemetry
---------
vcpkg collects usage data in order to help us improve your experience.
The data collected by Microsoft is anonymous.
You can opt-out of telemetry by re-running the bootstrap-vcpkg script with -disableMetrics,
passing --disable-metrics to vcpkg on the command line,
or by setting the VCPKG_DISABLE_METRICS environment variable.

Read more about vcpkg telemetry at docs/about/privacy.md
```

I don't know if this means a successful installation. When I try to search or install a package, it says

> vcpkg search [opencv2]
> command not found: vcpkg

How could I fix it?

Comment: Add it to your PATH. Your operating system doesn't magically know that the executable you build should now be executable from anywhere on your system.

Comment: I think it's reasonable for tools to update paths themselves. I added a feature request to do this or at least update the guide so it's clear it doesn't bother https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/28600

Answer (score 0):

Try `./vcpkg search opencv2` command inside of vcpkg installed path.